# How to find 2 parameters with gradient descent method in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, gradient-descent

I have a few lines of code which doesn't converge. If anyone has an idea why, I would greatly appreciate. The original equation is written in def f(x,y,b,m) and I need to find parameters b,m.

```
  np.random.seed(42)
  x = np.random.normal(0, 5, 100)
  y = 50 + 2 * x + np.random.normal(0, 2, len(x))

  def f(x, y, b, m):
      return (1/len(x))*np.sum((y - (b + m*x))**2) # it is supposed to be a sum operator

  def dfb(x, y, b, m): # partial derivative with respect to b
      return b - m*np.mean(x)+np.mean(y)

  def dfm(x, y, b, m): # partial derivative with respect to m
      return np.sum(x*y - b*x - m*x**2)

  b0 = np.mean(y)
  m0 = 0
  alpha = 0.0001
  beta = 0.0001
  epsilon = 0.01

  while True:

      b = b0 - alpha * dfb(x, y, b0, m0)
      m = m0 - alpha * dfm(x, y, b0, m0)

      if np.sum(np.abs(m-m0)) <= epsilon and np.sum(np.abs(b-b0)) <= epsilon:
          break
      else:
          m0 = m
          b0 = b
      print(m, f(x, y, b, m))
```

Comment: Why do you think that the iteration should converge?

Comment: That's how the method works, so I was told... maybe I am not doing it right(.

Comment: I printed `np.sum(np.abs(m-m0))` and `np.sum(np.abs(b-b0))` on each iteration and saw that they both quickly became NaN. During previous iterations, the second sum was fluctuating a lot, jumping from `0.006` to `2835422.576`, then from `1044.909` to `1.22e+16` (!). This could be a sign of the gradient "bouncing" across some kind of "trench" in your function because the `alpha` coefficient is too large _or_ because the gradient is incorrect. I think you should double- and triple-check your derivatives

Comment: @ForceBru thank you! The function that has to be minimized is the sum of squares and I was not sure how to use the sum operator in numpy. Could you confirm if np.sum() works? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both derivatives got some signs mixed up:

```
def dfb(x, y, b, m): # partial derivative with respect to b
  # return b - m*np.mean(x)+np.mean(y)
  #          ^-------------^------ these are incorrect
  return b + m*np.mean(x) - np.mean(y)

def dfm(x, y, b, m): # partial derivative with respect to m
  #      v------ this should be negative
  return -np.sum(x*y - b*x - m*x**2)
```

In fact, these derivatives are still missing some constants:

- `dfb` should be multiplied by `2`
- `dfm` should be multiplied by `2/len(x)`

I imagine that's not too bad because the gradient is scaled by `alpha` anyway, but it could make the speed of convergence worse.

If you *do* use the correct derivatives, your code will converge after *one* iteration:

```
def dfb(x, y, b, m): # partial derivative with respect to b
  return 2 * (b + m * np.mean(x) - np.mean(y))

def dfm(x, y, b, m): # partial derivative with respect to m
  # Used `mean` here since (2/len(x)) * np.sum(...)
  # is the same as 2 * np.mean(...)
  return -2 * np.mean(x * y - b * x - m * x**2)
```